# iPhone NSDate - get time in milliseconds and store in coredata

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm implementing iphone app with coredata functionality.
I've an attribute in entity "NSDate" which stores the date and time when the record is added.
I'm adding records at a faster rate. About 1 record per 25 milli seconds
I want to store the date along with milli seconds so that I can retrieve the data in descending order.
How can I do this?

The comments and answers are correct.
But how can I retrieve the stored milli seconds data along with other records in descending format?

Comment: You should accept one of these answers as both of them are correct.

Comment: I would say an answer is **"you are already storing milliseconds in your managed objects"**, but the latter part of the question is how to sort them in descending order? Consider updating your question to emphasise that if you still need it answered

Answer (score 2):

An `NSDate` uses `NSTimeInterval` which has better than millisecond accuracy.  If you want to skip `NSDate` you can use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` which returns the same value directly.  Below that is `gettimeofday()` which returns a `timeval` with up to microsecond accuracy.

`NSTimeInterval` and `CFTimeInterval` are both type double, so just multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

`NSDate` calls `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` calls `gettimeofday()` so they all have the same accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the milliseconds of the day through:
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSince1970]
and the NSTimeInterval is a long long, so you can save it into everywhere you want